# failing to convert numbers in parenthesis within a CSV file, to a SQL database as negative numbers, via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, expression, type-conversion

I am trying to import data into a SQL Server database from an excel CSV file and some of the columns' rows contains values like (123.45) and (678.90) and they should be negative values. I need to transform that data to save in the table as -123.45 and -678.90. The columns in the destination table are in decimal(19,2) data type. 
I have tried the following in conditional split transformation editor and failed

```
REPLACE([QuantityUnits],"(","-")
REPLACE(QuantityUnits,')','')
```

I have tried the following in Derived Column Transformation editor and failed...

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([QuantityUnits],”(“,”-”),”)“,””)

SUBSTRING([QuantityUnits],1,1) == "(" ? REPLACE(REPLACE([QuantityUnits],"(","-"),")","") : [QuantityUnits]

LEFT([QuantityUnits],1) == "(" ? REPLACE(REPLACE([QuantityUnits],"(","-"),")","") : [QuantityUnits]

LEFT([QuantityUnits],1) == "(" ? -1*(SUBSTRING([QuantityUnits],2,(CHARINDEX(")", [QuantityUnits])-1))) : [QuantityUnits]

CASE WHEN LEFT(QuantityUnits,1) = '(' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END * CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(QuantityUnits,'(',''),')','') AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 

FINDSTRING("(", QuantityUnits, 1) <> 0 : SUBSTRING(QuantityUnits, FINDSTRING ("(", QuantityUnits, 1) + 1, FINDSTRING (")", QuantityUnits,1) - 1 - LEN(FINDSTRING ("(", QuantityUnits,1) )) 

FINDSTRING(QuantityUnits,"(",1) > 0 ? SUBSTRING(QuantityUnits,FINDSTRING(QuantityUnits,"(",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(QuantityUnits,")",1) - 1 - FINDSTRING(QuantityUnits,"(",1)) : QuantityUnits 

(DT_R8)(REPLACE(REPLACE([QuantityUnits],"(","-"),")",""))
```

I have tried changing the data type in the flat file connection manager to string data type and that doesnt help

The csv file's problem columns have negative values that are represented like (2.5) and values with over 3 digits represented like " 1,074 ". The quotes are handled by my specification of the text qualifier but I am stuck on converting the negative values.
I used a Flat File Connection Manager with one file to verify i have the setup correct. When I go to Preview, my data lines up fine. However, I am trying to use a Multiple Flat Files Connection Manager because I have several files that I need to move from one folder

using VS2010

Answer (score 0):

What data type is the column? All of your examples (good on you for trying) are for string columns.

Have you tried this expression:  `-QuantityUnits`

By 'failed' do you mean you got an error or got an undesired result?

Don't use a conditional split, use a derived column.

Comment: the data type was being read in by SSIS as numeric, even with the parentheses. i wanted to read it in as a string to fix the data before adding it to the destination table which has data type numeric for the columns i have the issue with. you have a great suggestion that i did not try though, however, i didnt use that because not all values in that column has negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured out my problem. since i cant change the data type for existing columns in the Derived Column transformation, i went to the advanced editor of the Flat File Source task. On the Input and OUtput Properties tab, under Flat File Source Output > Output Columns, I had to change the data type properties there. Now everything works the way we expected.

Comment: Why are you converting to string just to make the number negative?